# AngularJS directive for C3 chart not displaying all graphs

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, c3.js

I am working with C3 charts for the first time and came across the angular directive of it called angular_c3_simple. https://github.com/wasilak/angular-c3-simple

I tried this with static data and it all worked fine but with the JSON data through service it is not working as expected.

I am trying to display 2 different graphs but it is displaying just the first graphs correctly but for the second graph it is showing undefined value.

Please help me out with this, not sure where I am missing.

Here is my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/NYxGjWGRzj4XVzc5XjpG?p=preview

```
<div class="row">
  <c3-simple id="chart" config="chart"></c3-simple>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <c3-simple id="chart1" config="chart1"></c3-simple>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the bindto option in the configuration, so, the graph was not shown correctly.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y1AgUG4NBntY5cjRQWAb?p=preview)

```
app.controller('analyticsController', function($scope, analyticsService, c3SimpleService, $http, $q) {
  console.log("I have entered here");
  var chart_size = {    width: 480, height: 280 };
  var chart_legend = {position: 'bottom'};
  $scope.chart = {};
  $scope.chart1 = {};
  analyticsService.getCounts()
    .then(function (dataattr){
      $scope.chart= {
                data: {
                columns: [
                    ['Production', dataattr.data.meta_charts_wl.wl_in_production],
                    ['Experimental', dataattr.data.meta_charts_wl.wl_in_experimental],
                    ],
                    type : 'donut',
                    colors: {
                    Production: '#1E91CF',
                    Experimental: '#FBA6A6',
                },
                },
                donut: {
                    title: "Area details:",
                    },
                size: chart_size,
                legend: chart_legend,
                bindto: "#chart"
        };
        $scope.chart1= {
                data: {
                columns: [
                    ['Production_1', dataattr.data.meta_charts_wl.wl_policymatched],
                    ['Experimental_1', dataattr.data.meta_charts_wl.wl_policy_not_matched],
                    ],
                    type : 'donut',
                    colors: {
                    Production_1: '#1E91CF',
                    Experimental_1: '#FBA6A6',
                },
                },
                donut: {
                    title: "Area details:",
                    },
                size: chart_size,
                legend: chart_legend,
                bindto: "#chart1"
        };
    })      
});
```

Comment: Don't worry, this kind of mistakes happen all the time. glad this could help you.